# Displaying array objects within a array with Angular ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple post that gets my json objects.

Inside my json I have 2 or more campaigns, campaigns is a array.

within a campaign array I have slots, slots is a array that has 1 or more base_image within.

I display on screen for each campaign.

- `max_slots`
- `c_name`
- `slots.base_image`

so that I can show each campaign name, maximum slots allowed and the images associated within each campaign.

**AIM**

I am trying to have a upload image and preview image for each campaign so you only see the image preview to the campaign your uploading it to.

**PROBLEM**

At the moment I upload a image and it shows on the preview for all campaigns, not the individual campaign.

*See image bellow:*

[image: preview in table]

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="Dashboard">
    <!--FIRST ng-repeat-->
    <div ng-repeat="campaign in campaigns" class="campaign-container">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>{{campaign.c_name}} {{$index}}</h1>
            <strong>This Campaign you are allowed {{campaign.max_slots}} Images</strong>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Select File</th>
                    <th>Preview Image</th>
                    <th>Add to list</th>
                    <th>Images</th>
                    <!--<th>Remove Image</th>-->
                    <th>Save Campaign</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td> <!--UPLOAD IMAGE-->
                        <div class="upload-new">
                            <input id="fileinput" ng-model="file" type="file" ng-model-instant="" name="file"
                                   accept="image/*"
                                   onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage(this)">
                        </div>
                        <!--END-->
                    </td>
                    <td>  <!--PREVIEW IMAGE-->
                        <div class="preview">
                            <img style="height: 100px; width: 100px" ng-src="{{preview}}" alt="preview image">
                        </div>
                        <!--END--></td>
                    <td>
                        <button ng-click="addImage()">Add image</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div ng-repeat="slot in campaign.slots" class="slot">
                            <img ng-click="addImage()" style="height: 100px; width: 100px" ng-src="{{base_image}}"
                                 alt="slot image">

                            <button ng-click="removeImage(slot)">Remove Image</button>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                    <!--<td>Remove button to be here</td>-->
                    <td>
                        <button ng-click="SaveImage()">Save to API</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--END FIRST ng-repeat-->
</div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
    .controller('Dashboard', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {

        $scope.campaigns = [];
        $scope.preview = '';
        // $scope.slots = [];
        $scope.maxSlots = [5];// this dynamic

        $scope.uploadImage = function () {
            // console.log('we are here');
            input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
            file = input.files[0];
            size = file.size;
            if (size < 650000) {
                var fr = new FileReader;
                fr.onload = function (e) {
                    var img = new Image;

                    img.onload = function () {
                        var width = img.width;
                        var height = img.height;
                        if (width == 1920 && height == 1080) {
                            $scope.preview = e.target.result;
                            $scope.perfect = "you added a image";
                            $scope.$apply();

                        } else {
                            $scope.notPerfect = "incorrect definitions";
                        }
                    };
                    img.src = fr.result;
                };

                fr.readAsDataURL(file);
            } else {
                $scope.notPerfect = "to big";
            }
        };

        $scope.addImage = function (index) {

            if ($scope.campaigns[index].slots.length < $scope.campaigns.maxSlots) {
                $scope.campaigns[index].slots.push({
                    "slot_id": $scope.campaigns[index].slots.length + 1,
                    "base_image": $scope.preview,
                    "path_image": ""
                });

            } else {
                window.alert("you have to delete a slot to generate a new one");
            }
        };

$scope.GetData = function () {
            $http({
                url: "http://www.site.co.uk/ccuploader/campaigns/getCampaign",
                method: "POST",
                date: {},
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            }).then(function (response) {
                // success
                console.log('you have received the data ');
                // console.log(response);
                $scope.campaigns = response.data;
                console.log("logging campaings", $scope.campaigns);
                //$scope.slots = response.data[0].slots;
                //$scope.maxSlots = response.data[0].maxSlots;

            }, function (response) {
                // failed
                console.log('failed getting campaigns goo back to log in page.');
                // console.log(response);
            });
        };

        $scope.GetData();
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only one `preview` variable in your controller, but you need one per `campaign`. You may want to pass the index of the campaign into your `uploadImage` function.

I'm not sure if the way you're doing file inputs is correct (haven't done it much myself), but you need something like this:

Template:

```
<input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage(this, $index)">

<img ng-src="{{campaign.preview}}" alt="preview image">
```

Controller:

```
$scope.uploadImage = function (element, index) {
    // Remove this - there are many file inputs with this ID. Use the element or index arguments?
    // input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
    // ...

    if (width == 1920 && height == 1080) {
         $scope.campaigns[index].preview = e.target.result;
    }
}
```

As mentioned in my comment above, you were also calling `input = document.getElementById('fileinput');` to get the file input, but `ng-repeat` will have created many inputs with that ID. Maybe you should use the input or index that is passed into `uploadImage(this, $index)`. If for some reason you still need to use `getElementById` instead of using the element you passed in, you could generate unique ID's using the index:

```
<input id="fileinput-{{ $index }}"
```

**Edit: The OP used the answer above with a few modifications:**

**HTML**

```
<input id="fileinput-{{ $index }}" ng-model="file" type="file" ng-model-instant="" name="file" accept="image/*" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadImage(this)">
```

**Controller**

```
    $scope.uploadImage = function (element, index) {
            console.log(element);
            console.log(element.id);
            str = element.id;
            str = str.substr(str.indexOf('-') + 1);
            console.log(str);
            index = str;

            // console.log('we are here');
            input = element;
            file = input.files[0];
            size = file.size;
            if (size < 650000) {
                var fr = new FileReader;
                fr.onload = function (e) {
                    var img = new Image;

                    img.onload = function () {
                        var width = img.width;
                        var height = img.height;
                        if (width == 1920 && height == 1080) {
console.log('we are here');
                            $scope.campaigns[index].preview = e.target.result;
                            // $scope.preview = e.target.result;
                            $scope.perfect = "you added a image";
                            $scope.$apply();

                        } else {
                            $scope.notPerfect = "incorrect definitions";
                        }
                    };
                    img.src = fr.result;
                };

                fr.readAsDataURL(file);
            } else {
                $scope.notPerfect = "to big";
            }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks for this makes sense. ill get this implemented test and get hopefully accept your answer.

Comment: just trying to fix a arror im getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: $index is not defined` the once its working ill accept answer

Comment: Are you naming the function parameter `index` or `$index`? In the template it has to be `$index`, but in the function I named it `index`

Comment: Yes javascrip function its index and html its $index

Comment: Is anything getting passed into the function? What if you pass some string just to test?

Comment: Ill test now, 3 mins

Comment: Usually you'd just call `uploadImage(...)` instead of all of that `...scope().uploadImage(...)`. I'm not sure if you did that because working with file inputs is odd. Maybe you can create a live example.

Comment: I can add the modification in your answer if you like

Comment: Sure, if it's pretty different maybe add it to my answer but as a separate section

Comment: almost the same, just could not get [$index] working so I used the element id